# Consumer works, Selector doesn't, why?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Here's a flutter widget with provider:

```dart
class FixtureList extends StatelessWidget {
  const FixtureList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppState>(
      builder: (context, appState, _) => ListView(
        children: appState.fixtures.isNotEmpty
            ? appState.fixtures
                .map((e) => FixtureListItem(
                      fixtureId: e.name,
                    ))
                .toList()
            : [],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Works great, but I'm using only `appState.fixtures`, so why not listen only to that part with a `Selector`, like so:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Selector<AppState, List<Fixture>>(
      selector: (context, appState) => appState.fixtures,
      builder: (context, fixtures, _) => ListView(
        children: fixtures.isNotEmpty
            ? fixtures
                .map((e) => FixtureListItem(
                      fixtureId: e.name,
                    ))
                .toList()
            : [],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This doesn't work, the `ListWiew` is not re-rendered when `notifyListeners` is called in `AppState`.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: How are you updating appState.fixtures?

Comment: @Nitrodon appState.fixtures is a List<Fixture>, and I just call .add on it. There's a notifyListeners call after it (AppState is a ChangeNotifier of course).

Comment: After notifyListeners is called in AppState, the selector method is correctly invoked again, but builder is not called after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in comments that you're just calling `add` on your fixtures list.  This means that you're actually returning the same `List<Fixture>` object every time.  The Selector then compares two references to the same object, concludes that they're the same, and doesn't rebuild your widget.

To make Selector work as intended, you will need to create a new `List<Fixture>` instance whenever you want to modify its contents:

```dart
fixtures = [...fixtures, fixtureToAdd];
notifyListeners();
```